# Lib installed locally not found

Tags: compiling, libraries

I wanted to install dungeon crawl without using sudo. SDL was not installed, so I installed it locally but it is not found when compiling crawl.

Here is how I did: I downloaded library "SDL2-2.0.5.tar.gz" and extracted it somewhere. From the new "SDL2-2.0.5" folder, I installed the library :

```
./configure --prefix=/home/vulpo/local
make
make install
```

I can see for example, that this file is on the expected location:

```
/home/vulpo/local/include/SDL2/SDL.h
```

I set my environment variables that way :

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/vulpo/local
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/vulpo/local/lib
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH was formerly **empty**.

I thought this would be sufficient to take my local SDL into account, but I get an error when installing my program:

```
vulpo@FOXBOX:~/.dungeoncrawl/crawl/crawl-ref/source$ make TILES=y
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
Package sdl2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sdl2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sdl2' found
Package sdl2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sdl2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sdl2' found
Package sdl2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sdl2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sdl2' found
Package sdl2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sdl2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sdl2' found
make -C rltiles all ARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu TILES=y
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/vulpo/.dungeoncrawl/crawl/crawl-ref/source/rltiles'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vulpo/.dungeoncrawl/crawl/crawl-ref/source/rltiles'
    CXX windowmanager-sdl.o
windowmanager-sdl.cc:21:24: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <SDL2/SDL.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:1550: recipe for target 'windowmanager-sdl.o' failed
make: *** [windowmanager-sdl.o] Error 1
vulpo@FOXBOX:~/.dungeoncrawl/crawl/crawl-ref/source$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/vulpo/local
vulpo@FOXBOX:~/.dungeoncrawl/crawl/crawl-ref/source$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/home/vulpo/local/lib
```

It does not work either by including every `/home/vulpo/local/*` directories in my Path.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/vulpo/local/bin:/home/vulpo/local/include:/home/vulpo/local/lib:/home/vulpo/local/share
```

So what is the correct way to use my local SDL in a program compilation?

Comment: The `PATH` variable is used for locating executable programs - it has no role in locating program header files or libraries. Run `./configure --help` to see if there is a specific variable you can set for the SDL location; if not, try setting your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to point to the location of the local `.pc` file(s) corresponding to your `--prefix` (probably `/home/vulpo/local/lib/pkgconfig` - but check).

Answer (score 0):

As you want to make this as user and not root, you will also need the dependencies available to the session.

```
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
```

Try downloading and adding the freetype2 package to your projects directory.